# 200 success code in Apache log but 504 error in the browser for the same request

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, amazon-elb, 504

Apache logs 200 (success) code but browser shows 504 Gateway timeout error for the same request.

Also, it times out just after aws load balancer idle time out value which is 1200 (20mins).

I do not find any log entries for the requests which times out (504) in the load balancer access logs.

I have tried increasing aws load balancer idle timeout value from 600 to 1200. but still times out.

Below is 200 success code logged in the apache access log.

`[22/Sep/2023:08:38:10 +1000] "GET /pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=UserRequest&id=588730& HTTP/1.1" 200 214618`

Load balancer health check running periodically which is 200 code

`GET /pages/UI.php HTTP/1.1" 200 9540 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"`

Am I missing anything to troubleshoot? Any clue of what can be happening?

Please note that it works all fine for other requests. For example, `https://example.com/pages/UI.php?operation=details&class=UserRequest&id=738424&` I can see it in the Apache log, ELB logs as well as it displays content well in the browser.

Comment: A gateway timeout indicates that a reverse proxy is involved. Please provide the relevant configuration parts from the proxy and the backend server.

Comment: Are you sure that 200 code is logged in Apache for the very same request that the user had received 504? You absolutely need to make request URLs unique enough to guarantee you traced the request down to the final back-end.